# Express js chat application:404 error on socket.io.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to develop a chat application using Express js(jade template ) and `socket.io`.Here is my `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var app = express();
//start chat with socket io
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  console.log("connection");
  socket.on('send message',function(data,callback){
    var msg=data.trim();
    if(msg==null){
      callback("enter a messsage");
    }else{
      console.log("chat message"+msg);
      io.sockets.emit('new message',{msg:msg});
    }
  });
});
//end socket
```

Here is my `chat.js` file on client side

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var $message=$('#message');
    var $messageForm=$('#send-message');
    //opens a connection and send to sever
    $messageForm.submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             socket.emit('send message',$message.val(),function(data){
              console.log("data"+data);
             });
             $message.val('');
           });
    //read the chat messages from users
    socket.on('new message',function(data){
        console.log('data.msg');
    });
});
```

`chat.jade` file

```
<form id="send-message">
<input type="text" id="message">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script src="http://localhost/api/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I will get 404 error on this file `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Also  get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` in chat.js script.I think this is because of missing `socket.io.js` file.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues.
Serving static files in your jade templates you should be using something like this:

```
link(rel='text/javascript', href='/js/socket.io.js')
```

These files will normally be contained within a `public` directory in your express app. 
Then in your `app.js` you should have something like:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Its explained here on the express site - http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

**Elsewhere**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined  

$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

This is because you havent defined `io` on your client. You call `connect` on something called `io` but havent declared/defined `io` anywhere.

**Also**
You havent created a socket server on your app side. You should be doing something along the lines of:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});  
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
        socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
        });
    });
```

**Example**
Socket.io have an example chat app on github that you should use as reference.
Your `chat.js` would be the equivalent of their [public/main.js](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/public/main.js)
Your `chat.jade` is equivalent to their [public/index.html](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/public/index.html)
and your `app.js` matches their [index.js](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js)

Comment: I think my problem with `io.connect`.

Comment: I have maually attached socket.io file in my chat.jade.Now the 404 error is solved but `io reference error` is still persists

Comment: Checkout the link above `public/main.js`. In that file they instantiate socket using `var socket = io();`

Comment: if you replace `var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3000');` with `var socket = io();` you are getting the same `io is not defined error`? Is it the same line that is causing the error? Is your `socket.io` file referenced before your `chat.js` file?

Comment: and is `socket.io` before `chat.js` in your chat.jade file?

Comment: Edits in the above answer - you werent creating a socket server.

Comment: Now my server is running,but again the same reference error:)

Comment: Another edit above but at this stage I would recommend looking at the example provided and comparing code and see if you can figure it out from there. What is different in the example that might cause it to work that is not in your code.

Comment: here is a good example of the same tutorial it looks like you were doing. https://github.com/DonaldDerek/Chat-Node. Has a couple of differences that might help such as wrapping your client side code in `window.onload` before calling it in `document.ready`